# Pandas Dataframe: df adding a column from another df1 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, addition

Needs help: I couldn't put my head together with this one and I tried different while & for loop possibilities, but all got errors.

Basically, I would like to add a column from **df1** to **df** based on its corresponding 'inst_id'.

Here's my **df**

[image]

And here's my **df1**

[image]

As you can see, they both have different index length and I cannot just directly append values from df1 to df.

So I would like to achieve something like this based on the 2 dataframes:

```
new_df = ({'inst_id':100654,100654, ..., 494904},
      {'inst_name':'Alabama A&M University','Alabama A&M University', '...', 'Access Careers- 
       Islandia' })

import pandas as pd
pd.dataframe = new_df
```

**TYIA!**

Answer (score 2):

If i'm understanding you correctly, you could use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
new_df = df.merge(df1, on='inst_id')
```

Comment: I knew I'm complicating myself. LoL! And surely, never done this before as a newbie...

That works instantly... I thought I have to recreate a whole new dictionary with 15000 indeces

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a inner join between those two tables using  [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='inst_id')
```

Example

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"inst_id": [100654, 100654, 100654, 100663, 100663], "award_lvl":[5,7,9,2,5]})
>>> df1
   inst_id  award_lvl
0   100654          5
1   100654          7
2   100654          9
3   100663          2
4   100663          5
>>>
>>>
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"inst_id":[100654, 100663],"inst_name":["Alabama A & M", "Uni of Alabama at Bir"]})
>>> df2
   inst_id              inst_name
0   100654          Alabama A & M
1   100663  Uni of Alabama at Bir
>>>
>>>
>>> new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='inst_id')
>>> new_df
   inst_id  award_lvl              inst_name
0   100654          5          Alabama A & M
1   100654          7          Alabama A & M
2   100654          9          Alabama A & M
3   100663          2  Uni of Alabama at Bir
4   100663          5  Uni of Alabama at Bir
```

Comment: Yes Manikanta, that works too, similar to kait's suggestion...Appreciate both!

Answer (score 0):

```
data1 = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
data2 = [['tom', 'A'], ['nick', 'B'], ['juli', 'A'],['Mark', 'D']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Name', 'Section'])  
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df1,on='Name',how='outer')
print(df3)
```

you will get it as below.
Name Section Age
0 tom        A  10
1 nick       B  15
2 juli       A  14
3 Mark       D  NaN